# Copy a multidimensional Array of bool into another array

Tags: c#

How can I copy an Multidimensional Array of bool into other. The one dimension array use the length but I am not sure that this is right for multidimensional array.

```
bool[][] OldArray
bool[][] NewArray = new bool[][];

Array.Copy(NewArray,OldArray,NewArray.length)
```

Comment: Are you aware that with your code the inner arrays are just copied by reference ? Is that what you want or do you need a deep copy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Burland is correct; that's a jagged array, and cannot be copied using `Array.Copy`. However, since you're initializing it, you can use LINQ.

```
bool[][] oldArray;
bool[][] newArray = oldArray.Select(innerArray => innerArray.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

The inner copying internally uses `Array.CopyTo`, so it's not as slow as an enumeration would be.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a multidimensional array, it's a jagged array (array of arrays).

```
bool[,] multiDimArray;
```

is multidimensional

```
bool[][] jaggedArray;
```

is jagged. The difference is that a multidimensional array is always rectangular while a jagged array doesn't have to be.

To copy a mutlidimensional array (the first case) you just multipy the lengths of each dimension together, because (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or column).

For a jagged, you'll need to loop through the first dimension and then `Array.Copy` each inner array in turn.

Comment: Thank you for the definition. It was really useful. Can I use Linq to do it?

Comment: @Devsined: Sure - looks like Douglas beat me to it.